# Поиск частичных совпадений в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть бд, вида id|ip|text|
Делаю запрос:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `Ippred`, `Text` FROM `pred` WHERE `Ippred` like '%".$ip."%'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
if ($result > 0){
echo '<div style="color:black;width:50%;">';
echo 'Ваш IP адрес был найден в базе' ;
echo '</div>';
```

Попробовал реализовать через лайк, все равно выводит только есть будет полное совпадение, а мне надо, чтобы если пользователь зашел под ip, например, 178.71.137.107, то если в базе есть ip 178.71. , то он выводил, что ip найден

Comment: ну значит ваш запрос должен в итоге выглядеть как ... like '178.71.%', ну может еще % в начале если у вас там в поле несколько ip (что не верно, если так). Так что заранее отрежьте от ip начало и проверяйте именно по нему

Comment: "все равно выводит только есть будет полное совпадение" http://risovach.ru/upload/2015/06/mem/babka-wat-shta_83735635_orig_.jpg